# Paste functionality of clipboardData API in javascript getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')

Tags: javascript, html

Html button code as follows i tried simple onclick function on button and also event on second button

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<button id="button">Paste</button>
```

Javacript code as follows

```
function myFunction() {

      var clipboarddata =  window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');    
      console.log("paste value" + clipboarddata);
}

var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(event){
   alert(event.target);
   event.preventDefault();
   var clipboarddata =  window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');    
   console.log("paste value" + clipboarddata);
});
```

both the ways i am getting same error

Comment: Did you mean `event.clipboardData`?  Which browser?  Browser support of clipboards is not uniform.

Comment: [`window.event`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/event) is deprecated.

Comment: Every browser i am getting- cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getData')
    at HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#main").on("paste",function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var clipboarddata =  window.event.clipboardData.getData('text');    
      console.log("paste value" + clipboarddata);
      $('#pasteData').text(clipboarddata);
    });
  
});

Comment: with above i tried it is working but on button click function i am not able to do it

Comment: may be i am using jquery for this clipboard API that is why it is working on paste event function but on buttonclick i am having simple function in javascript but i want this to work on buttonclick in javascript

Comment: @SSJ jQuery is irrelevant. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Then use the `event` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`navigator.clipboard.readText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText) instead.

```html
<button id="button">Paste</button>
<script>
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  navigator.clipboard.readText().then(text => console.log("paste value:", text));
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is working but i dont want popup to allow , directly it should work

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid permission from user while pasting content

Comment: @SSJ No. It's a matter of security.

Comment: and in firefox it is not allowed....i want all browser support code for paste functionality